# How to name foreach matrix columns?

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

Just a question about a neat way to name the result matrix of a foreach loop. This works, but it's a bit verbose, I wonder if there is a simpler method:

```
r = foreach( i=seq(5), .combine=rbind, .final=function(res) { colnames(res) = c("First", "Second"); return(res) } ) %dopar% { c(i, i+1) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the column names in the RHS of your `%dopar%`:

```
foreach(i=seq(5), .combine=rbind) %dopar% { c(First=i, Second=i+1) }
```